# C# Object oriented proggramming issue - overriding methods

Tags: c#, oop, casting, polymorphism

Consider this code in C#:

```
    public class A
    {
        public A()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A");
        }
        public virtual void One()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("One of A");
        }
        public virtual void Two()
        {
            One();
        }
    }

    public class B : A
    {
        public B()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B");
        }
        public override void One()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("One of B");
        }
        public override void Two()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Two of B");
        }
        public void Three()
        {
            base.Two();
        }
    }
```

and the main:

```
A a3 = new B(); //"A" and then "B"
a3.Two();' //"Two of B"
((B)a3).Three(); //"One of B"
```

Why does the last line in the main program writes 'One of B'?
Why when it executes One() it goes to the One() of B?

Comment: Please write a better title based on your _specific_ problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: you scoped the cast with the extra parenthesis

Comment: if i will do (B)a3.Three() it would give me a compilation error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Break down what each method calls -

```
((B)a3).Three();
```

calls

```
B.Three();
```

which calls

```
A.Two();
```

which calls

```
A.One();
```

but `A.One` is *virtual*, which means that the system has to look at the *actual* type of the object at runtime to determine *which* `One`  will be called.

Since the object referenced by `a3` is a `B` (even though you *declared* it as an `A` variable reference), `B.One()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Because your variable `a3` is type B, and because type A's Two method is marked as `virtual`, the compiler infers that the method that should be called is type B's overridden implementation of `One()`.

Answer (score 0):

Because method One() of class A is declared virtual and it finds an override in class B, so it picks the override.